# How to find "How many times lesser"?

Tags: calculus

I currently have two values of a variable GPP.The base value is $6.48$ (for the years $1850-1950$) and the new value is $1.98$ (for $1951-2005$). How can I determine that how many times the new value is lesser than the base value? I would like to compare the new value with base value and how many times it is lesser.

(I am just asking "the times" , not a $%$ increase or decrease)

Comment: I guess you are looking for something else then your wording is asking. For your literally question, why not take $\frac{6.4}{1.98.}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE, Hallie. Your question isn't very clear. If you could, please explain better what you want.

Comment: I did edit my question for clarity

Comment: I guess the misunderstanding is a language problem. You are not asking something like "how many eggs are 4 eggs given 3 *times*"  but rather about time spent on a clock?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is either $1.98/6.48 = 0.30555$, that is, $1.98$ is $0.30555$ times lesser than $6.48$. Or $1.98$ is $6.48/1.98 = 3.2727$ times lesser than $6.48$.